# Get Vendor ID and Device ID of soundcard using Inno Setup

Tags: audio, wmi, inno-setup

I want to integrate a feature into my setup which gets installed if a certain range of soundcards of a certain vendor is installed in the computer.

I have read about the [Win32_SoundDevice class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but unfortunately I do not understand how to implement it into the script.

Can somebody please explain to me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By which property (or group of properties) of that WMI class will you recognize that range of soudcards ?

Comment: I thought by VendorID and DeviceID but I just looked through the properties again, there is no VendorID... Maybe Manufacturer and Name/ProductName would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I wouldn't consider this as a reliable way for recognizing whether certain audio devices are present in the system, here is a possible implementation of the [`Win32_SoundDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class which you've mentioned. Query used in the following example filters audio devices by the given manufacturer and then iterates the returned recordset and checks if the just iterated device matches one of the given product names:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
function IsSupportedSoundDeviceAvailable(const Vendor: string;
  Models: TStrings): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  WQLQuery: string;
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemServices: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;

  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');

  WQLQuery := Format('SELECT ProductName FROM Win32_SoundDevice ' +
    'WHERE Manufacturer = "%s"', [Vendor]);

  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(WQLQuery);
  // if the query returns at least one record, then...
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    // iterate each record in the recordset and if its ProductName exactly
    // matches an item in the passed Models collection, then return True
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
      if Models.IndexOf(WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I).ProductName) <> -1 then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Models: TStrings;
begin
  Models := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // fill the exact product model names into the collection
    Models.Add('Creative AudioPCI (ES1371,ES1373) (WDM)');
    // call this function to determine, whether there's at least one device
    // that matches the product name of the vendor given in the first param
    if IsSupportedSoundDeviceAvailable('Creative Technology Ltd.', Models) then
      MsgBox('Sound device is available.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  finally
    Models.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: just a note, the `ItemIndex` property is not present in Windows XP.